# How can one read/recover deleted files

Tags: java, file

I need some points on:

> How can one read/recover deleted files, in Java code. I've used before
>   for file read&write operations, clases from java.io, such as
>   FileInputStream, FileReader, etc., but that's obviously not going to
>   work

So anyone, some points, theory, maybe a link... there has to be a way!

Comment: @aioobe sorry. Same question, no JAVA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760396/low-level-access-programming-languages-deleted-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that on some OS it is nearly impossible to restore a deleted file.

When you talking about Windows filesystems, then with some JNI code you may access the filesystem and reset the delete flag.

Obviously if it is your program that delete files, you may move them into a bin folder, from which you can restore if needed.

Another option could be to write some service that monitors filesystem activity and may copy files into a bin for later restore. Read about [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Answer (score 9):

This is impossible to do in Java (at least without dropping to native level through JNI).

Reason being that the standard Java API is a high level API, and this type of business requires low-level file-access. A deleted file is simply not visible through the interfaces that the java.io API provides.

Comment: Tell me more about this "low-level file-access" thingy

Comment: Haha.. well, basically you need to go beyond the structure of the file-system and directly read the bytes and bits manually. This is obviously extremely file-system / OS dependent. You may for instance not be allowed to do it unless you're logged in as administrator or if the file system is mounted. I strongly suggest you use a tool for this.

Comment: I've used software tools such as SanDisk RescuePRO before... i'm not planing to build one... but I am interested in the "HOW IT'S MADE" part + how to do it using JAVA.

Comment: @pulancheck1988: When the user deletes a file on their computer, the OS (low-level) will delete the file.  Any other programs that may have had access to that file can do so no longer as it has been deleted.  The JVM is one such program - that is, when you delete that file, the JVM (i.e. Java code) no longer has access to it (makes sense, it's been deleted, right?).  Now you come along and you happen to have some insider knowledge that it's possible to retrieve that deleted file - the JVM doesn't know this, and thus there's no way for your Java code to access the deleted file.

Comment: OK. OK. Remove the Java part then... and add any of the other programming languages that do have a lower-level access. How? How?

Comment: formulate and post (and link to) a new question. this is getting off-topic regording the original post.