# java program which delete file and recover it

Tags: java, data-recovery

This is my code to delete '.txt' files from specific folder(/home/user). But once it is deleted I don't know how to recover these deleted files.

Please show me some example code (if possible), to achieve this.

Is it possible in java? If so then please help me (I am happy to use any other language.)

```
import java.*;
import java.io.File;
class  CountFiles
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String dirPath="/home/user";
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        int s=files.length;
        System.out.println("Number of files in folder "+s);
        for(int i=0;i <s; i++)
        {
            if (files[i].isFile())
            {
                String FilesName = files[i].getName();
                System.out.println(FilesName);
                if (FilesName.endsWith(".txt") || FilesName.endsWith(".TXT"))
                {
                    boolean success = files[i].delete();
                    vif (!success) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");
                    else System.out.println("file deleted");
                }
                System.out.println("file deleted out side.....");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you should be able to recover them?

Comment: *I know,it is not possible in java.* Then **what** are you asking?

Comment: The only way that you can guarantee that it can be done, is to make a copy somewhere before you delete them.

Comment: is it possible with other languages?

Comment: No, not without first making a backup of the file, or using a library that makes a backup of the file, or one that hooks into the system trash/recycle folder if available, else it makes a backup of the file.

Comment: There are some ways to recover data in some situations (Only if the file link was deleted, but the data remains on the drive) by directly reading from the HDD, but they are NEVER EVER 100% reliable.

Comment: so how work recovery software like Recuva or Puran File Recovery

Comment: good idea, thank you sorifiend, but how (it's possible in java)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to recover it from the trashcan/recycle-bin/???  We often don't think of that as "Deleting" so people may not be answering the right questions here.  It is possible but it might take some jni (both to "move to the trash" instead of truly deleting and to recover afterwards).  If that will work for you, you first need to figure out how your operating system uses it's recycle/trash functionality.

Comment: Tip: Add @ElliottFrisch (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in Java, however for low level or OS specific tasks it may be better to use a native language.

The below info applies to both Java and other languages:

---

If you have control of the files before they are deleted then you can simply make a copy/backup of the file before you delete it.

---

If you want to recover data from a system trash/recycle bin then you need a specific solution for each OS.

---

However, if you do are not able to backup the files first, and do not have access to a trash folder, then you can NEVER EVER be 100% sure that you can recover the data (See edit below for more details). You can however read raw data from the storage device. This is an incredibly complex and advanced subject. If you have to ask the question then you should not be trying to write code to do it without first doing a lot of your own research.

Before reading on, refer to this answer showing how you can read raw bytes from a storage device: [How to recover deleted files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431506/how-to-recover-deleted-files-using-java)

After reading the accepted answer you also need to consider:

- You can access the drive sector by sector, but you will have to
  interpret the data differently for different file systems (FAT, NTFS,
  HPFS, and more)
- You cannot use a file path to get a deleted file, you need to scan the whole drive and make an educated guess at what to recover,
  or ask for user input so they can choose what to recover.
- The task can be a long and complex one, and you have to interpret the raw data to see if it is a valid plain text file, as well as finding it's start and end.

Edit to include the comment from Bill:
Once a file has been deleted, any further action that the computer takes (Including using recovery tools) has the potential to write over the data that you want to recover. The best solution is to force shutdown the PC, and clone the drive so that data recovery can be done on another PC using the clone while keeping the original safe.

Comment: Also anything you do on  your system after deleting the file has the potential to overwrite it's data, so starting a java app at that point is one of the worst things you can do.  If it's already running then--well as @sorifiend said--you had control of the file so why didn't you copy it???

Comment: I now understand the principle of recovering (theoretically) Thank you so much sorifiend and Bill I am searching now how to find the start and the end of a file by recovering the data bit by bit directly from the hard disk.